# Separate chaining with priority queue (using std::map)

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap, hashtable, priority-queue

I just start learning hash table and while trying with std::map I come up with this question: when using separate chaining method to solve collision, can I use `std:: priority_queue` instead of just list?

For example there is a big group of people and I have the information of their first names and ages, and what I want to get is sorted lists of people with same first name e.g. 'David' base on their ages.

So to do this I first use their first name as the key to put these people into the map, and then people with same name that cause the collision should be solved with std::priority_queue base on age.

Is this the right way to solve this problem? 
And I just realize that I don't really know the mystery behind `std::map`, is it using separate chaining or linear probing to solve collision? I couldn't find the answer for that.

Simple code I have for the question I described that might help clarify it a bit:

```
class people {

public:
people(string inName, int inAge):firstName(inName), age(inAge){};
private:

string firstName;
int age;


}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

string name;
int age;

name = "David";
age = 25;
people  aPerson(name, age);
//This is just an example, there are usually more than two attributes to deal with.


std::map <string, people> peopleList;

peopleList[name] = aPerson;

//now how do I implement the priority queue for collision first names? 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: since I need O(1) search, I should use unordered map instead of map.

Comment: `std::map` isn't a hash at all, it's a binary tree. Also, you can write a comparator for a compound `(name,age)` key without using a nested container.

Comment: O(1) for searching is required, since map is a binary tree, it doesn't satisfy this right?

Comment: `std::map` is sorted, and is logarithmic time for search & insert. `std::unordered_map` is unsorted as the name suggests, constant time for search & insert, and is implemented as a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have a mapping between a name and a single `people` object. You need to change your mapping to be a map between a name and a `std::priority_queue`, with a custom comparator for the priority queue:

```
auto comparator = [](const people& p1, const people& p2) -> bool
    { return (p1.age < p2.age); }

std::map<std::string,
         std::priority_queue<people, std::vector<people>, comparator>> peopleList;

// ...

peopleList[name].push(aPerson);
```

Comment: thannks a lot, and it would be the same for unordered map right?